# Is debugging possible in drools 5.1.1?

Tags: debugging, drools, drools-flow

I was working with drools 5.5.0.Final release and was able to debug the .drl file perfectly fine, but on switching to drools 5.1.1, I am not able to debug. Tried setting up the drools 5.1.1 runtime but still facing the same issue. In addition, if I just change the drools version back to 5.5.0.Final in pom.xml for the same project, the debug works fine. Is it that drools didn't support debug in its prior releases or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe putting breakpoints on drl for Java was temporarily broken in between, but was fixed in a more recent release.  I think you should be able to either switch to the MVEL dialect, or use a more recent version of Drools where it was fixed again.